# How Cant I Reference a Text File in Html / Make a way to post on my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I run a website where people where I work post things often, but I'm the only one that knows html and css, so I have to format their posts, and add them to a page/ create a new page for them, I want to know if there's a way that I could add a way to either have them just make a text file that I would just have to reference in the code, or a different way that would allow them to write their posts on the site and have the posts automatically add themselves to the site?

Comment: Why not just use a simple CMS system?  Look into Wordpress/Drupal/Joomla.  You can put the css on the site initially, and let them update as they please.

Comment: You can upload or save a file in a database.  Then read the files on that directory or retrieve them from the database.  Whatever rendering tool you use will set the CSS boilerplate.  Use a CMS as suggested or re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is a common problem in a developers life. When you create a site for your client that regularly posts news updates or blog articles one has to manually write all the code needed. But normal people can't write the necessary HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so often it's all up to the developer.

#### Luckily, this is where CMS (Content Management Systems) come in

This Wikipedia page explains CMS in detail: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management

Another friendly article on CMS: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/content-management-system

Basically, what these systems do is:

**1.** A developer first sets up the CMS for the client. The developer writes all the necessary code for the CMS to work.

**2.** After getting the CMS ready, it is deployed in production and the administrators have admin right of the CMS (e.g. for creating new posts).

**3.** Then the clients can easily log into their website and  **use the CMS interface to create new posts**. With a CMS, creating new posts only requires filling in some forms and no coding.

**4.** Finally, the CMS handles all the required HTML/CSS coding and appropriately creates the new posts. This way the process goes much smoother.

That being said, there are quite a few CMS that are often used right now, like **WordPress, Drupal and Joomla!**

WordPress: https://wordpress.org/

Drupal: https://www.drupal.org/

Joomla!: http://www.joomla.org/

You can Google some more and learn how to work with these systems. I'm sure you'll find one that fits your needs.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: We're using godaddy hosting, and they have a drupal addon, could i integrate drupal into the site I've already coded? or would I have to start over from scratch? Sorry, I was looking into CMS but I don't know much about how they work

Comment: You definitely can't magically get Drupal to import what you've done thus far - you'd need to build a Drupal theme. I'd avoid GoDaddy-installed Drupal too - it's likely to be several versions out of date.

Comment: @maxir101 Like ceejayoz helpfully commented, you need to build a Drupal theme. It'll require some efforts but from my experience it's not that hard. Actually, you can reuse most of the code you have and with a little more configuration, you'll have a Drupal site up and running. Building custom Drupal themes requires some extra skills, so go to Drupal's website and start learning the basics. For a start, you can use the GoDaddy provided Drupal addon.

Comment: @AbraarArique thank you very much! I'll definitely look into how to use drupal and try to get it working with it.